# How can I add an image as a characteristic of another image?

Tags: java, android, image, graphics

In Java I have created the following class which extends ImageView to create a character... I want to know if it is possible to add another image of the item my character is holding (see method "addWeapon()") which will move when my character moves (see method "warriorMover(..)").  Basically, I was wondering if it is possible to make the "weapon image" sort of a "characteristic/part" of the main character?

```
public class WarriorEntity extends ImageView
{
private kingsColor kingColor;
private weapons weaponId;

private int kingSide;
private int warriorId;
private int nLeft;
private int nTop;

public WarriorEntity(Context context)
{
  super(context);
}

public void defineWarrior(kingsColor a1, weapons a2, int a3, int a4, int a5, int a6)
{
  kingColor = a1;
  weaponId = a2;
  kingSide = a3;
  warriorId = a4;
  nLeft = a5;
  nTop = a6;

  switch (kingColor)
  {
    case blue:
      this.setImageResource(R.drawable.bluewarrior);
      break;
    case green:
      this.setImageResource(R.drawable.greenwarrior);
      break;
    case purple:
      this.setImageResource(R.drawable.purplewarrior);
      break;
    case red:
      this.setImageResource(R.drawable.redwarrior);
      break;
    case white:
      this.setImageResource(R.drawable.whitewarrior);
      break;
    case yellow:
      this.setImageResource(R.drawable.yellowwarrior);
      break;
  }
  this.setId(warriorId);
  this.setOnClickListener(WarriorClick);
  setImagexy(this, nLeft, nTop, 20, 30);
}

public void addWeapon()
{
  switch (weaponId)
  {
     case bowandarrow :
        break;
     case mace :
        break;
     case spear :
        break;
     case sword :
         // - Here I would want some code to add the weapon image which as if it were part
              of the same image as the character... moves/reacts with the character.
        break;
  }
}

public void warriorMover(int leftX, int topY)
{
  setImagexy(this, leftX + 8, topY - 3, 20, 30);
}
```

"setImagexy" is a custom method which does exactly that... moves an image to a given location on the screen.

Comment: Why not add a Weapon class instead of using only an enum, and have that extend ImageView as well?

Comment: Yeah, that's actually the idea.  The enum just represents what type of weapon the character is holding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Different approaches could be used :
making a copy of the default sprite and drawing the sword on top of it (a good approach in case you don't need to update the sprite too often

or you could just render the sword on top of the sprite after you have drawn the character sprite:

```
render_loop()
_>draw_characterSprite()
__>draw_equipment()
```

Comment: I did think of drawing different sprites with the different weapons, but then I would end up with 5 or 6 extra images per character.

Comment: you'd have only 1 extra image that you will use as buffer to save the pre-drawn character with its equipment. Why would you need 5 or 6 ?